# Should I put ‘there’ after ‘which’ in a given example?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

Go along the street **at the end of which there is** the railway station.

Comment: With or without _there_ looks fine to me. _Go along the street, at the end of which, there is the railway station._

Comment: I'd prefer to go along the street that has the railway at its end.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence shouldn't be correct without comma. You can say any of the following sentences :

1) Go along the street, at the end of which, there is the
railway station.

2) Go along the street,  at the end of which  is the
railway station.

3) Go along the street. At the end of that, there is the
railway station.

4) Go along the street. At the end of that  is the
railway station.

Comment: How do you know the restrictive sense (pointing out _which_ street to go down) isn't intended?